# WiFi access point shows up many times, can't connect

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm sitting right next to an access point, but the WiFi menu shows very low signal strength and I can't connect. When I run wavemon or iwlist, the access point shows up several times with different channels:

```
Finnsalarna        00:25:84:16:0B:00 100%, -32 dBm, ch  64, 5320 MHz ESS, Spectrum Mgmt
Finnsalarna        00:25:84:16:0B:00  33%, -87 dBm, ch 104, 5520 MHz ESS, Spectrum Mgmt
Finnsalarna        00:25:84:16:0B:00  34%, -86 dBm, ch 112, 5560 MHz ESS, Spectrum Mgmt
Finnsalarna        00:25:84:16:0B:00  33%, -87 dBm, ch 128, 5640 MHz ESS, Spectrum Mgmt
Finnsalarna        00:25:84:16:0B:00  36%, -85 dBm, ch 136, 5680 MHz ESS, Spectrum Mgmt
```

The top one appears to be the "real" one, and the signal strenth varies nicely when I walk around the building. I have several other access points that are out of range in the scan below, but this issue seems to come and go with all of them. WiFi is working normally on my iPhone with the same AP.

Any ideas about what's going on here? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, fresh install just a week ago.

Comment: Is the router set to a fixed channel (recommended) or Auto?

Comment: It's automatic (DFS), which is required by EU regulation for most of the 5 GHz band and preset by the manufacturer. All access points are Cisco Aironet 1131AG.

Comment: Does `iw reg get` agree? Is it GB or 00-unset?

Comment: It is `country SE: DFS-ETSI`